# Set/Apply security policy to web services/ SOAP service using .net/c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, wcf-security

I am new to using .Net.

Please help me with finding, The easiest way to apply a security policy to the soap web service in c#.

I am using X509store to find a certificate from a store and now want to set security policy to make a web service call.

Rough code:

```
        var cert = new X509Certificate2();

        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root,StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates;

        X509Certificate2Collection signingCert = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, certName, false);

        cert = signingCert[0];
```

Now, I want to set the security policy and add this certificate and then make a web service call.

So is there any simple way to call or any function available in .net ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the official documentation, it has both client and server code sample, you may find it useful. [WCF - Message Security with a Certificate Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-a-certificate-client)

Comment: @bradbury9 thank you, it's helpful. Is there any other way also?